# Nodejs/Mongoose: Cannot PUT HTML Form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I seem to have problem updating user's profile in the database using the PUT method. When I change the current email address, or fill in the "about me" section, the server returns "Cannot POST /settings". I would like the "email" part to be filled (it cannot be empty), but the "about me" part is optional (it can be empty).

I tried searching online but none of the answers are related to my problem. I believe the issue lies in the "route" section (HTML and MongoDB schema are also added for your reference, the HTML is actually EJS template). Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/settings?_method=PUT" method="POST">
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<%= currentUser.firstName %>" readonly>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<%= currentUser.lastName %>" readonly>
     </div>  
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">About me</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="aboutMe" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="<%= currentUser.email %>">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Birthday</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<%= currentUser.birthday %>" readonly>
   </div> 
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Gender</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<%= currentUser.gender %>" readonly>
   </div> 
   <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary btn-settings" role="button">Cancel</a>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-settings">Save</button>
</form>
```

**NodeJS Route:**

```
router.put("/", function(req, res){
   var newData = {aboutMe: req.body.aboutMe, email: req.body.email};
   User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, {$set: newData}, function(err, user){
      if(err){
        res.redirect("back");
      } else {
        res.redirect("/settings");
      }
   });
});
```

**MongoDB Schema**

```
var UserSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    aboutMe: String,
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    birthday: {type: String, required: true}, 
    gender: {type: String, required: true}, 
});
```

Comment: You mix PUT and POST.

Comment: `router.put("/settings")`

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for your reply. I don't think it is the problem of 'router.put("/settings")', as I have included it in the app.js file.

Comment: `router.put("/" ... ` handles PUT requests to "/" not to "/settings".

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes, I understand. But that's not the problem since I have specified the route to be "/setting" in the main app.js file, which NodeJS will run.

Comment: I just found that I forgot to include the "method-override" package, as express.js doesn't support PUT method. Thanks guys for your replies.

Comment: Then you probably want to add this piece of code to the question. It should be [minimal, yet complete and  verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)